# std::getline is returning multiples of the same line

Tags: c++, getline

I'm parsing a .txt file in order to make a Exp Calculator and I'm getting a wierd error where it will double up any line that has more then one line from the stream. I'm using this code to open and close the file to check for changes and only print the changes.

This is what the text file looks like..

```
[11:58:18] Mind increased by 0.000013 to 28.160389
[11:58:18] Mind logic increased by 0.000015 to 33.213428
[11:58:18] Miscellaneous items increased by 0.000061 to 59.381138
[11:58:18] Repairing increased by 0.000782 to 35.52212
[11:58:19] Mind increased by 0.000015 to 28.160404
```

When I add the Sleep to slow it down it does get each line 1 by one and print them to the console but after it completes it moves on to printing every line that has more then 1 line in the stream..

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios::streampos file_end;
    ifstream file ("C://Users//Matthew//wurm//players//Maximillian//logs//_Skills.2013-03.txt");
    if(file.is_open())
    {
        file.seekg( ios::beg, ios::end );
        file_end = file.tellg();
        file.close();
    }else{
        cout << "Unable to open file";
    }

    while(true)
    {
        ifstream file ("C://Users//Matthew//wurm//players//Maximillian//logs//_Skills.2013-03.txt");
        if (file.is_open())
        {
            file.seekg( ios::beg, ios::end );
            streampos new_end = file.tellg();

            if(new_end > file_end)
            {
                file.seekg(file_end);

                string line;
                while(getline(file, line))
                {
                    if(!line.empty())
                        cout << line << endl;
                    Sleep(1000);
                }

                file_end = new_end;
            }
            file.close();
        }else{
            cout << "Unable to open file";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output... take note of the time stamps. I have no idea why it's doing this...

```
[16:42:36] Mind logic increased by 0.000015 to 33.349262
[16:42:36] Miscellaneous items increased by 0.000053 to 59.777897
[16:42:36] Repairing increased by 0.000694 to 36.59152
[16:42:37] Mind increased by 0.000013 to 28.270370
[16:42:37] Mind logic increased by 0.000019 to 33.349281
[16:42:38] Mind increased by 0.000013 to 28.270384
[16:42:38] Mind logic increased by 0.000015 to 33.349297
[16:42:38] Repairing increased by 0.000694 to 36.59222
[16:42:39] Mind logic increased by 0.000015 to 33.349312
[16:42:40] Repairing increased by 0.000694 to 36.59291
[16:42:42] Mind increased by 0.000015 to 28.270399
[16:42:42] Mind logic increased by 0.000015 to 33.349327
[16:42:42] Repairing increased by 0.000694 to 36.59361
[16:42:43] Mind increased by 0.000013 to 28.270412
[16:42:43] Mind logic increased by 0.000015 to 33.349342
[16:42:44] Mind increased by 0.000013 to 28.270426
[16:42:44] Mind logic increased by 0.000019 to 33.349361
[16:42:44] Repairing increased by 0.000694 to 36.59430
//I added this afterwards to break up what I printed out first... why did it reprint all the times that had 2 or more lines at once?
[16:42:36] Miscellaneous items increased by 0.000053 to 59.777897
[16:42:36] Repairing increased by 0.000694 to 36.59152
[16:42:37] Mind increased by 0.000013 to 28.270370
[16:42:37] Mind logic increased by 0.000019 to 33.349281
[16:42:38] Mind increased by 0.000013 to 28.270384
[16:42:38] Mind logic increased by 0.000015 to 33.349297
[16:42:38] Repairing increased by 0.000694 to 36.59222
[16:42:39] Mind logic increased by 0.000015 to 33.349312
[16:42:40] Repairing increased by 0.000694 to 36.59291
[16:42:42] Mind increased by 0.000015 to 28.270399
[16:42:42] Mind logic increased by 0.000015 to 33.349327
[16:42:42] Repairing increased by 0.000694 to 36.59361
[16:42:43] Mind increased by 0.000013 to 28.270412
[16:42:43] Mind logic increased by 0.000015 to 33.349342
[16:42:44] Mind increased by 0.000013 to 28.270426
[16:42:44] Mind logic increased by 0.000019 to 33.349361
[16:42:44] Repairing increased by 0.000694 to 36.59430
```

Comment: `file.seekg( ios::beg, ios::end );` is probably a typo.  Begin or end?

Comment: The offset is the begining of the file and I wanted it to be set to the end... I tried it several ways and they works the same. (0, ios::end)

Comment: I see, I changed it back to 0 but it's not the issue sadly.. 2 days trying to figure this out lol... Any idea as to why I'm getting this wierd out come?

Comment: What does "every line that has more then 1 line" mean?

Comment: Well since the data is changing constantly sometimes the stream has more then 1 line. When it's one line it works fine when it's 2 or more it will repeat all the lines after the first.

Answer (score 1):

After the `getline()`-loop, the read position in the stream is not guaranteed to be equal to `new_end`, because someone might have written to the file after you determined `new_end`, but before or while you were reading from it.

This leads to some lines beeing printed, folllowed by adjusting `file_end` to a value that suggests the lines have not been printed yet. These lines will be printed a second time during the next iteration of your outer `while`-loop.

Update `file_end` by calling `tellg()` again, not by assigning from `new_end`. You have to call [`clear()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/) on the stream before doing the update, because `std::getline()` is called until the `failbit` on the stream is set, and this leads to `tellg()` returning `-1` (i.e. not the actual position of the end of the file).

Comment: Usually, you have to lock files explicitly if you want to prevent concurrent access. MS-Windows is an exception, it locks files by default. I guess this also holds for Microsoft's implementation of the C++ standard library (it can take a non-standard third argument in the constructor of [std::basic_fstream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8et8s826.aspx)). I do not know how other implementations of the C++ standard library for MS-Windows handle locking.

Comment: I've tried several different way of updating new_end and file_end but I'm having no luck getting it working right.

Comment: The stream returned from `std::getline()` is considered `true`, unless the `failbit` or the `badbit` on the stream is set, regardless of whether `eofbit` is set. Your inner loop therefore iterates until the `failbit` or the `badbit` on the stream is set. If the `failbit` or the `badbit` on the stream is set, `tellg()` returns `-1`. Clear the `failbit` after your inner loop by calling [`clear()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/) before calling `tellg()`.

Comment: That fixed it... I was going to answer this but I can't since I'm new.. Thanks everyone for the help. More or less  update new_end after the reading then I update file_end to tellg() after I clear() only when there is something to read.

Comment: Yep, the iostreams library has some pitfalls. I still have to frequently consult the documentation. Glad I could help.

Comment: I read a bunch of other solutions to the "getline stuck on a single line" problem expecting to see something like the clear() function, but instead the solutions were usually filled with other junk. Calling clear() before reading the next line worked perfectly for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to clear() the tellg() function before the update and I also update the file_end and new_end differently.

```
while(true)
{

    ifstream file ("C://Users//Matthew//wurm//players//Maximillian//logs//_Skills.2013-03.txt");

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        if(new_end > file_end)
        {
            file.seekg(file_end);
            string line, output;
            while(getline(file, line))
            {
                //if(!line.empty())
                //    cout << line << endl;
                int f1 = line.find("] ")+2;
                int f2 = line.find(" increased ");
                if(f1 != line.string::npos && f2 != string::npos)
                {
                    output.append(line, f1, (f2-f1));
                    output += " ";

                    f1 = line.find(" by ") + 4;
                    f2 = line.find(" to ");
                    if(f1 != string::npos && f2 != string::npos)
                    {
                        output.append(line, f1, (f2-f1));
                        output += " ";
                    }
                }
                cout<<output<<endl;
                output.clear();
            }
            file.clear();
            file_end = file.tellg();
        }
        file.seekg( 0, ios::end );
        new_end = file.tellg();

        file.close();
    }else{
        cout << "Unable to open file";
    }
}
```